# MSIE Browser height?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Does anyone know how to get the browser height in IE7+ with javascript? I've seen several ways to get the document or the body height but this is not the same. window.innerHeight works fine in firefox and other browsers, but ie doesnt seem to support it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var windowWidth = -1, windowHeight = -1;

if(typeof(window.innerWidth) == 'number') { //Non-IE
    windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
} else if(document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) { //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
```

That's worked pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the actual size of the browser window, use the following properties:

#### Mozilla based browswers

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
```

#### Microsoft Internet Explorer

```
document.body.offsetWidth
document.body.offsetHeight
```

Here is some code that I use:

```
var winW = 630, winH = 460;

if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") == -1) {
 if (navigator.appName=="Netscape") {
  winW = window.innerWidth;
  winH = window.innerHeight;
 }
 if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
  winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
  winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
 }
}
```

Comment: document.body.offset* is for IE5 (and IE6+ in "quirks mode", which you don't want to be using). In standards mode body is only as high as the page content inside it and you need to look at document.documentElement instead.